# Command to copy and delete subtree in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there a command in org-mode that copies and deletes a whole bullet point (*with its content*)? I use that as a way to move tasks into other sections.

So in other words:

```
* Task A
   Content
** Task B
   Content
* Task C
```

I want to be able to easily copy and delete the section 'Task A' so that after execution I would get

```
* Task C
```

and I can paste the task subtree under the previous task.

PS: I know I can move the subtree down one task at a time. But I have a long document and I want an easier way of moving the tasks.

Thanks

Comment: I fail to understand how the answer gets upvoted but not the question. My best guess is lack of personal research shown. Could you tell us what you looked for in the documentation before asking the question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`C-c C-x C-w` will kill the subtree, then you can paste it somewhere else with `C-c C-x C-y`.

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html.

You could also look into the refile command, which lets you move a subtree around:

http://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-copy.html#Refile-and-copy

Comment: How would I find out about these commands from within emacs' help? If I do C-h ? a subtree, I find `org-cut-subtree`, which seems to do the same job, but it show no shorcut (I assume tat would be `C-c C-x C-w`).